# C: How to unit test a function that does not take any arguments and has main program linked to unit test framework?

Tags: c, unit-testing

I am using [minunit](http://www.jera.com/techinfo/jtns/jtn002.html) test framework for C application. I have a bunch of functions that does GUI work and I am not sure what needs to be done. 
I have created a library of my main program and linked it to my unit test framework so I have access to all the functions.

This is sample function I need to test.

```
int
main_gui_init()
{
    GladeXML  *main_window;
    main_widgets_t *widgets;
    zlog_category_t *zc;

    zc = zlog_get_category(LOG_CATEGORY);

    /* load the interface */
    main_window = glade_xml_new(MAIN_GLADE_FILE, NULL, NULL);

    if (!main_window) {
        zlog_error(zc, "Failed to load main interface");
        return -1;
    }

    widgets = (main_widgets_t *) malloc (sizeof(main_widgets_t));

    if (!widgets) {
        zlog_error(zc, "Failed to allocate memory for widgets");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Initialize widgets we are interested in */
    main_gui_init_widgets(main_window, widgets);

    /* connect the signals in the interface */
    main_gui_register_callbacks(main_window, widgets);

    zlog_info(zc, "Main gui init done.");
    return 0;
}
```

This is how I would like to test it:

```
/* Test main_gui_init() */
char* run_all_main_gui_init_test()
{
    /* Functions are not yet written but the name 
       shows what needs to be tested */ 
    mu_run_test(test_main_gui_init_valid);
    mu_run_test(test_main_gui_init_invalid_main_window);
    mu_run_test(test_main_gui_init_malloc_fail);
}

/* Starting point. Specify all the functions that needs to be tested here */
char* run_all_main_gui_tests()
{
    run_all_main_gui_init_test();
}
```

How do I write test program? I could write a stub for each test case, for example, for function glade_xml_new() to return NULL, but since I have linked the main program, it will not allow me to have the same definition of same function twice.

What is it I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a mocking library, I would not advise doing that yourself. A good option is [cmocka](http://cmocka.org/) It uses on the c library as a dependency and will allow you do redefine your objects with mocks.

Otherwise, in C your only option is to use the pre-processor or the linker to mock out your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out. Is it necessary to de-link the main program from the unit test module?

Comment: If you use cmock, all you will have to do is to link your test file with mocks instead of your real object files.